# Bash Script using read needs to stop executing on Ctrl+D

Tags: bash, shell-script, input, read

I need to write a script that will add a line to a text file if <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

But, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is pressed, I need to exit that loop in the bash.

```bsh
touch texttest.txt
LINE="0"
while true; do
    read LINE;
    if [ "$LINE" == "^D" ]; then
            break
    else
            echo "$LINE" >> texttest.txt
    fi
done
```

Currently have something like this but cannot figure out how I am do exit the while loop when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is pressed instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overthinking it. All you need is this:

```
cat > texttest.txt
```

Cat will read from STDIN if you've not told it different. Since it's reading from STDIN, it will react to the control character <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> without your having to specify it.  And since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>  is the only thing that will finish the `cat` subprocess, you don't even need to wrap it in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

The following would do:

```bsh
while read -r LINE ; do
  echo "$LINE" >> texttest.txt
done
```

1. you don't need to touch the file first
2. you don't need to initialize the `LINE` variable
3. <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> closes stdin, which makes `read` exit with non-null (false) exit code

Comment: whoever edited my answer, I disagree.